# how to connect oracle 11g r1 database

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

i am trying to connect oracle database with my java program using eclipse IDE, i have added JDBC driver **ojdbc6.jar** into class path.

am using:
Database is: **Oracle 11g r1 Enterprise edition**.
Operating system: **windows 7 64bit**.
JDK version: **1.7.0**.

i have tested in browser with url as "localhost:1158" it opens oracle login page and also successfully logged in with username and password as "SYSTEM" and "12345", same using in my code, but while trying to run java program getting a exception.

my java program for testing database connection is:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Connect 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1158:v$instance","SYSTEM","12345");
            System.out.println("connected.."+con);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**Exceptions are**:

```
java.sql.SQLException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:199)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:480)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:413)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:508)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:203)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:33)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:510)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at abhishek.Connect.main(Connect.java:12)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:328)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:421)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:630)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:206)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:966)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:292)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: //localhost
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:127)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:126)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:306)
    ... 12 more
```

can anyone tell me what's wrong i have did and the meaning of the exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port `1158` is for the DbConsole interface and won't work with JDBC.

The default port for the Oracle listener to which JDBC should connect is is port `1521`.